# QGIS - Spatial Join with Raster and Vectorial files

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, spatial-join

I have two layers, a raster (arr_ker) and a vector (Polygon), as can be seen below:

[image]

In QGIS, I need to add the raster data to each of the entities found in Polygon. It would be ideal as an average.

Is that possible?

PD: The shared image is in ArcMap, but I did it comfortably, since I would have to do the raster classification again in QGIS. Hopefully it will be understood that I need the solution in QGIS in this question.

Comment: You need to use [Zonal Statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics).